# Given a program, how can we determine the number of save/restore operations executed?

Tags: c

Suppose we have the following simple program:

```
int foo() {
    int a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, w;
    c = abs(c);
    c = c + b + 7;
    for (w = 0; w<10; w++) {
      b += bar(b);
    }
    return c;
  }

int bar(int v) {
    int a = 1, b = 2;
    a += v + b;
    printf(“v=%d\n”, v);
    return v;
  }
```

If `foo()` is called once, how can we determine the number of save/restore operations executed for variables `a`,`b`,`c`, and `w` when stored in a *caller*-saved register vs *callee*-saved register?  It may be that I'm not understanding terminology, but an explanation of the process in which one would determine how many load/stores each variable has in each situation would be great.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You can determine this by looking at the machine code generated by your compiler.

Comment: We have no way of knowing without looking at the assembly.  The answer will be different depending on what the optimizer does, so the answer is not really very meaningful.

Comment: For what processor are we talking about here?

Comment: I'm sorry, this is exactly how the problem is written.  Can any meaningful information be given in some generic sense of what the question is asking?

Comment: @BobJohn: Not really.  It's entirely dependent on what your compiler chooses to do.

Answer (score 2):

The only answer is "at least zero".

1. Modern compilers will delete `a`, `b`, and `c` from `foo()`.  Since those variables won't exist, they will never be loaded or stored.
2. The `w` variable may exist or it may be eliminated by unrolling the loop.
3. The `a` and `b` variables in `bar()` aren't needed so they will probably get deleted as well.

### What the output might look like:

The compiler might produce output like this:

```
int foo()
{
    printf("v=%d\n", 2);
    printf("v=%d\n", 4);
    printf("v=%d\n", 8);
    printf("v=%d\n", 16);
    printf("v=%d\n", 32);
    printf("v=%d\n", 64);
    printf("v=%d\n", 128);
    printf("v=%d\n", 256);
    printf("v=%d\n", 512);
    printf("v=%d\n", 1024);
    return 12;
}
```

As you can see, there are no variables to save or restore in this optimized version.

### Update

When compiling with `-O2`, GCC saves the `rbx` and `rbp` registers which are callee-save on x86-64.  These registers are saved once and restored once.  GCC's output for `foo()` never calls `bar()`, it calls `printf()` directly.

```
foo:
        pushq   %rbp                ; save register rbp
        movl    $2, %ebp            ; b = 2
        pushq   %rbx                ; save register rbx
        movl    $10, %ebx           ; ctr = 10
        subq    $8, %rsp
.L4:                                ; begin loop
        movl    %ebp, %esi
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        movl    $.LC0, %edi
        call    printf              ; printf("v=%d\n", b)
        addl    %ebp, %ebp          ; b += b
        subl    $1, %ebx            ; ctr--
        jne     .L4                 ; end loop (when ctr == 0)
        addq    $8, %rsp
        movl    $12, %eax           ; return 12
        popq    %rbx                ; restore register rbx
        popq    %rbp                ; restore register rbp
        ret
```

Answer (score 0):

The terms "caller saved registers" and "callee saved registers" refer to registers that are saved by the caller of the function, and registers that are saved by the called function, respectively. What registers are which depends on the processor architecture, and the specification called "ABI" (Application Binary Interface) - this varies from processor family to processor family, and it is also often different between operating systems. But the basic principle is that the machine code that the compiler produces is built with certain expectations: Any function can freely use R0, R1, R2, and the caller must expect these to be modified in a call. R3-R6 are saved by the called function, and if the calling function uses R7 or R8, it must save those before calling any function. [This is an "arbitrary processor", which doesn't actually exist].

So to analyse your functions...

Let's pick apart this function first:

```
int foo() {
    int a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, w;
    c = abs(c);
    c = c + b + 7;
    for (w = 0; w<10; w++) {
      b += bar(b);
    }
    return c;
  }
```

The variable 'a' is not used, so can be removed. 
The function 'abs' can be resolved at compile-time, so that line can be removed. 
`c = c + b + 7;` can be resolved at compile time as 2 + 3 + 7 = 12.  We just move the constant 12 to the return statement and get rid of `c`. 
So, now we're left with:

```
int foo() {
    int b = 2, w;

    for (w = 0; w<10; w++) {
      b += bar(b);
    }
    return 12;
  }
```

That uses, at least, 2 registers.

Doing the same to the next function:

```
int bar(int v) {
    int a = 1, b = 2;
    a += v + b;
    printf(“v=%d\n”, v);
    return v;
  }
```

We can remove `a = 1, b = 2` and `a += v + b`, since `a` and `b` are not used. 
This leaves:

```
int bar(int v) {
    printf(“v=%d\n”, v);
    return v;
  }
```

Now, a clever compiler would inline `bar` into foo, now we get:

```
int foo() {
    int b = 2, w;

    for (w = 0; w<10; w++) {
      printf(“v=%d\n”, b);
      b += b;
    }
    return 12;
  }
```

Realistically, this can be done with two or three registers, plus whatever needs to be done for `printf` (and we can't really tell what that is...). The compiler may well go another step and "unroll" the loop, in which case one more register can be removed, possibly.

Comment: So let's say all variables are caller-saved first.  In the last case you've written of foo(), would w have 10 saves and 10 loads (save once before the function call, then load once after the function call?)  What if all variables are callee-saved?

Comment: Then there would still be ten saves and stores, just the other side of the return address on the stack. So instead of `w`, `ret`, `printf local var`, you'd get `ret`, `w`, `printf local var`. And yes, you'd expect that `w` is stored in a register that needs saving. Now, if we called a simple function that doesn't do much [rather than the "everything including the kitchen sink" like `printf`], then it may not be required to save ANY register [assuming there are some "scratch" registers], because the simple function can be performed with just scratch registers.